# NuGet not correctly updating project references

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Following an update of a local NuGet package, it looks like NuGet is not correctly handling the update of the project references.  For example, we have updated MyProject.Test to version 1.2; however, the project reference looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="MyProject.Test, Version=1.0.1.24568, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MyProject.Test.1.2.0\lib\net40\MyProject.Test</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Manually updating the reference seems to correct this (as does manually removing and re-adding the reference), but surely updating the NuGet packages using:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

Or simply updating the package in the Manage.. screen should do this for us.  Is there something extra that needs to be done to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

Surely updating the NuGet packages need use update-package without -reinstall. The function of command line "update-package -reinstall" is that：

> Removing a package and then trying to locate the same package in the
>   NuGet gallery with the **same version**

If you use this command before update package, NuGet will reinstall the old version package and restore the reference.
So you need update your MyProject.Test to version 1.2 using "update-package" before using the "update-package -reinstall" to restore references:

```
update-package -ProjectName projectname
```

Alternatively, simply updating the package in the Package Manager UI as you mentioned. Then you need not have do any other extra things to enable this.